# JS $.post not loading PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I copied the code from a YouTube tutorial, modified the database connection and SELECT items to connect to my existing DB, but I can't seem to get the JS to load the PHP file. In Chrome using the "inspect" tool, I can see that the JS file is loading, but when I click on GRAB on my HTML page, it doesn't do anything. Almost like the JS file is loading but not running.

Webserver folder structure:

```
    ROOT FOLDER
      test.html
      -AJAX (folder)
          name.php
      -JS (folder)
          global.js
      -CONNECTIONS (folder)
          dbase.php
```

HTML CODE

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>AJAX Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" id=name-submit" value="Grab">
    <div id="name-data"></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript File

```
    $('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {
        var name = $('input#name').val();
         if ($trim(name) != '') {
           $.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
                 $('div#name-data').text(data);
           });
         }
    });
```

PHP File

Comment: what output you got on console.

Comment: Are you sure that the path to `PHP` script is correct? Try adding the full path just for debugging. Also do a `console.log(data);` and echo something in the top of `PHP` script. See if that `echo` is returned.

Comment: I put the full URL with HTTP:// etc. and it still didn't load

Comment: During the tutorial he tested the Javascript with an ALERT which I tried and it didn't work...
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {
 alert(1);
});

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific about the console.log(data) - where to put it etc. :)

Comment: Put it in the `$.post` method, before `$('div#name-data').text(data);`

Comment: I added it to the $.post method but nothing happened in the console. I also added and echo to the PHP file, but didn't see it.

Comment: @Rayza `$.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {` should be `$.post('../ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {` the js is in a js folder so you need to move up one level and down another one (ajax)

Comment: @LelioFaieta - yeah I tried that as well. No difference. I even moved the PHP file into the same folder as the JS file to make sure it wasn't a folder issue...

Comment: Put the js inside the HTML page directly at the bottom before closing body tab

Comment: OK, so I've found 2 mistakes... in the HTML file I was missing a " in the line id=name-submit" and in the JS file ($trim(name) should be ($.trim(name). I've changed those and now it is loading the PHP file but it's not outputting anything on the HTML page

Comment: @Rayza can you post your php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why my PHP code was edited and removed from here, but I've ended up re-writing the whole PHP page. I added `or die(mysql_error());` to my SELECT statement and found that it needed me to specify my database in the FROM. I have multiple databases on my server and even though the DB is specified in the connection string it needed it again in the SQL Statement. The next problem I resolved was removing the `mysql_num_rows` as this was just not working like the demo did.

ORIGINAL PHP

```
    <?PHP
    if (isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty ($POST['name']) === false) {
           require '../db/connect.php';

    $query =mysql_query("
           SELECT 'names'.'location'
           FROM 'names'
           WHERE 'names'.'name' = '" . mysql_real-escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) . "'
           ");

    echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query, 0, 'location') : 'Name not found';
    }
    ?>
```

The original was far too complicated for what I wanted and also for me to problem solve it so I re-wrote it:

NEW PHP FILE

```
    <?PHP

    //I've intentionally left out the connection data..

    $sql_select = mysql_query("
          SELECT names.location
          FROM database_name.names
          WHERE names.name = '" . $_POST['name'] . "'
          ")
          or die(mysql_error());

    $sql_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select);

    echo $sql_fetch['name'];

    ?>
```

Thanks to those that assisted. Appreciated...

I am aware of the deprecated tags in the PHP file, but when I was copying from a demo so I wanted to get it working before updating it with new tags.

Answer (score 0):

First try to add a console.log('something') inside your javascript click function, right before the var name =... line, to see that your event is even firing. If not you need to register the event properly. Is the click function surrounded by

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {
        var name = $('input#name').val();
        if ($trim(name) != '') {
            $.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
                $('div#name-data').text(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Originally I didn't have it surrounded by the $(document) but adding that and the ending }); didn't make any difference. I put the console.log inside the click function but the console is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try using submit event

 $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('input#name-submit').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $('input#name').val();
            if ($trim(name) != '') {
                $.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
                    $('div#name-data').text(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```